# Selenium + JS: driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By(), 2000)) sometime gets stuck

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, wait, gettext

so by now I got my browser automation working mostly as intended. It is basically looping through a several `for` loops to test several hundres (or thousands) of combinations of settings.

But in mostly each run one function of mine gets stuck at the point of waiting for an `elementLocated` condition. The `getElementText()` functions returns the text of the given element using the xpath locator. If the given element can not be located, it shell return "no data". because of a very often refreshed DOM I had to workaround the standard `findElement()` way. The function is the following:

```
async function getElementText(xPathStringOfElement){
    await console.log ('starting getElementText() ...');
    let textOfElement = 'NO DATA';

await driver.wait(await until.elementLocated(By.xpath(xPathStringOfElement), 2000)).getText()
.then(async function (text0){
    textOfElement = text0;
},async function (err0){
    await console.log('ERROR: ' + err0);
    await console.log('...')
    await console.log('Wait for Element to be shown.')
    await driver.sleep(1000);
    await driver.wait(await until.elementLocated(By.xpath(xPathStringOfElement), 2000)).getText()
    .then(async function (text1){
        textOfElement = text1;
    },async function (err1){
        await console.log('ERROR: ' + err1);

    });
});
return textOfElement;
}
```

So what I expect it to do (and what succeeds several hundreds of times in a row) is, that if the `await driver.wait(await until.elementLocated(By.xpath(xPathStringOfElement), 2000)).getText()` waits for 2 seconds, the function jumps to `async function (err0){`
 and errors... But sometimes, and I do not see why, the `getElementText()` gets stuck and waits forever.

Does anyone have an idea, how I can improve my code here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After adding another `await` and using:
`await driver.wait(await until.elementLocated(await By.xpath(xPathStringOfElement), 2000)).getText()`
it seems to run fine now.